# Have many "get :index" within the same controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I want to test a controller which reacts different whether it's the first request of a logged in user or a subsequent. The code which differs is the following:

```
before_filter :init_guest_user

def init_guest_user
  @guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound # If session[:guest_user_id] is invalid
  session[:guest_user_id] = nil
  init_guest_user
end
```

I tried the following in my spec:

```
it 'finds the guest user for a subsequent request' do
  get :index
  expect {
    get :index
  }.not_to change(User, :count)
end
```

This works nicely. But the following fails:

```
it 'creates a new guest user if the previously existed one vanished' do
  get :index
  User.last.destroy

  expect {
    get :index
  }.to change(User, :count).from(0).to 1
end
```

It seems, that `@guest_user` persists between the two request, which isn't what I expected. What's going on here?

Comment: What is User.last? Can you inspect that? Are you sure that's the guest user? Relying on `.last` and `.first` to fetch the most recent record is never a good idea, especially if you have a default_scope defined.

Answer (score 1):

May be because the `@guest_user` is already initialised and it doesn't check the other conditions. I guess this will work

```
  def init_guest_user
   @guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)

 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound # If session[:guest_user_id] is invalid
  session[:guest_user_id] = nil
  @guest_user = nil
  init_guest_user
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I refactored a whole bit of the code, and now it seems to work as expected.